# Multidirectory makefile with pybind

Tags: c++, makefile, pybind11

I'm trying to create a pybind project with multiple subdirectories. I managed to get the example.cpp file working with the following command (link below):

```
c++ -O3 -Wall -shared -std=c++11 -undefined dynamic_lookup `python3 -m pybind11 --includes` example.cpp -o example`python3-config --extension-suffix`
```

https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/compiling.html#building-manually

It works right now by importing "example" and calling example.method. What I am trying to do moving forward is create a Makefile independent of cmake where I have the following directory structure and import classes when needed.

```
Top Level Folder
├── Makefile
├── Folder 1
│   ├── Makefile?
│   ├── example1.cpp
│   ├── example2.cpp
│   ├── example3.cpp
│   ├── ...
├── Folder 2
│   ├── Makefile?
│   ├── example1.cpp
│   ├── example2.cpp
│   ├── example3.cpp
│   ├── ...
```

I want to make the Makefile generic so that I can create a new folder with new cpp files and everything can work cleanly in python.  Some classes may use information from other classes in different folders and I'm having some difficulty doing this. Does anyone know how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Have a look at this: https://github.com/igagis/prorab
if you stat using it you will not have this problem at all :)